# Show there exists a number $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(b) = f(a) + (b-a)f'(a) + \frac{(b-a)^2}{2}f''(c)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Full question:
*Suppose that $f'$ exists and is continuous on $[a, b]$ and $f''$ exists on $(a, b)$, where $a < b$.
Show that there exists a number $c \in (a, b)$ such that
$$
f(b) = f(a) + (b-a)f'(a) + \frac{(b-a)^2}{2}f''(c)
$$*

Manipulating the above equation gives me

\begin{align*}
\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} &= f'(a) + \frac{(b-a)}{2}f''(c) \\
f'(c) &= f'(a) + \frac{(b-a)}{2}f''(c)
\end{align*}

The question suggests the use of the Mean Value Theorem. Using this for both $f$ and $f'$ gives me

\begin{align*}
f'(c) &= \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} \\
f''(c) &= \frac{f'(b) - f'(a)}{b - a}
\end{align*}

But I am stuck here. I tried formulating the equation of the tangent line through $(a, f(a))$ for $f$ as well as through $(a, f'(a))$ for $f'$ but to no avail. Is there some sort of manipulation for this which can help?

Comment: The mean value theorem doesn't say that the "c" found for $f(x)$ and the "c" found for $f'(x)$ are the same value.

Comment: OH RIGHT! But that makes me even more stuck.. I can't seem to find a relation between the two using MVT.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the Taylor expansion of f near a to the first order and use the Lagrange form of the remainder (the  remainder is of second order), then substitute b.

Answer (score 0):

So you are asked to prove Lagrange's form for Taylor polynomial of degree 1 for $f(x)$.

So let
$$F(t) = f(b)-\left[ f(t)+f'(t)(b-t) \right]$$
Differentating it gives
$$F'(t)= - \left[ f'(t)-f'(t)+f''(t)(b-t) \right] = -f''(t)(b-t)$$
Now let $\varphi(t)$ be any differentiable (and with derivative nonzero) on $[a,b]$ function and apply Cauchy MVT to the pair $F(t)$ and $\varphi(t)$
$$\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)} = \frac{F'(c)}{\varphi'(c)}$$
for some $c \in ]a, b[$.

In particular observe that for $\varphi(t) = (b-t)^2$ you obtain Lagrange remainder form, which you are required to prove.

Write if you will need help with applying Cauchy MVT

Comment: I am trying to solve the same problem as OP. How would I even know to come up with the equation for $F(t)$ in the first place, given that I have no knowledge of Taylor's Theorem at all thus far? I mean, is there any intuition behind it?

Comment: Sorry for late response, but this is like development of approximating f(x) by itse derivatives and F(t) is just convenient function taken from nowhere

Comment: It's alright! Hmm. But if it is taken from nowhere, how would I know to "cook" that up out of "thin air" then? I mean, there must be some idea starting from somewhere right haha.

Comment: Well, basically you are looking at what you need to derive and then search for something that will give that in convenient form. I mean it is in some sense the same as when we add and subtract something or conjugate.

Comment: @EthanMark also, as another approach to motivate observe that we havdto prove that there is some number c such that expression hold, i.e we had to prove the statement $f(b)=f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(c)(b-a)^2$ for some c. And observe that if I first consider $f(b)=f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)$ (basically Taylor's polynomial of first degree) I will have exactly $F(t)$ after moving all to the LHS and making $a$ vary

Comment: I see. Thank you :)